# Access denied when trying to authenticate with samba

Tags: debian, samba

I am working with samba for some time now, but I ran into a problem. I have multiple shares and multiple accounts, but the accounts do not have access to their defined shares.

- I have a debian 9 container in Proxmox;
- The root user is able to access all the shares (added it to samba
  with smbpasswd -a);
- I added new users using useradd and smbpasswd -a;

I have the following shares:

```
[Backup]
        browseable = yes
        comment = Backup folder
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/backup
        read only = no
        valid users = root mark nextcloud
        writable = yes

[Files]
        browseable = yes
        comment = General files
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/files
        read only = no
        valid users = root mark nextcloud
        writable = yes

[Movies]
        browseable = yes
        comment = Movies and music folder
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/movies
        read only = no
        valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
        writable = yes

[Pictures]
        browseable = yes
        comment = Pictures folder
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/pictures
        read only = no
        valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
        writable = yes

[Git]
        browseable = yes
        comment = Git folder
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/git
        read only = no
        valid users = root git
        writable = yes
```

When I try to connect with for example my files share, the users root and mark are able to access it, but the users nextcloud and plex are getting an access denied message.

testparm doesn't give me any errors though:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[Backup]"
Processing section "[Files]"
Processing section "[Movies]"
Processing section "[Pictures]"
Processing section "[Git]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[Backup]
        comment = Backup folder
        path = /mnt/backup
        valid users = root mark nextcloud
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775


[Files]
        comment = General files
        path = /mnt/files
        valid users = root mark nextcloud
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775


[Movies]
        comment = Movies and music folder
        path = /mnt/movies
        valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775


[Pictures]
        comment = Pictures folder
        path = /mnt/pictures
        valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775


[Git]
        comment = Git folder
        path = /mnt/git
        valid users = root git
        read only = No
        create mask = 0775
```

Full /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

#[homes]
#   comment = Home Directories
#   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
#   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
#   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
#   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
# to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
#   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
#;[netlogon]
#;   comment = Network Logon Service
#;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
#;   guest ok = yes
#;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
#;[profiles]
#;   comment = Users profiles
#;   path = /home/samba/profiles
#;   guest ok = no
#;   browseable = no
#;   create mask = 0600
#;   directory mask = 0700

#[printers]
#   comment = All Printers
#   browseable = no
#   path = /var/spool/samba
#   printable = yes
#   guest ok = no
#   read only = yes
#   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
#[print$]
#   comment = Printer Drivers
#   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
#   browseable = yes
#   read only = yes
#   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
#;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[Backup]
    browseable = yes
    comment = Backup folder
    create mode = 0775
    guest ok = no
    path = /mnt/backup
    read only = no
    valid users = root mark nextcloud
    writable = yes
# TODO: Make specific shares for devices that need to be backuped (Laptop, Phone and Tablet)

[Files]
    browseable = yes
    comment = General files
        create mode = 0775
    guest ok = no
    path = /mnt/files
    read only = no
    valid users = root mark nextcloud
    writable = yes

[Movies]
    browseable = yes
    comment = Movies and music folder
        create mode = 0775
    guest ok = no
    path = /mnt/movies
    read only = no
    valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
    writable = yes

[Pictures]
    browseable = yes
    comment = Pictures folder
        create mode = 0775
    guest ok = no
    path = /mnt/pictures
    read only = no
    valid users = root mark nextcloud plex
    writable = yes

[Git]
    browseable = yes
        comment = Git folder
        create mode = 0775
        guest ok = no
        path = /mnt/git
        read only = no
        valid users = root git
        writable = yes
```

less /etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:100:104::/var/spool/postfix:/bin/false
sshd:x:101:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:102:108::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
plex:x:1000:1000::/home/plex:/bin/sh
nextcloud:x:1001:1001::/home/nextcloud:/bin/sh
git:x:1002:1002::/home/git:/bin/sh
mark:x:1003:1003::/home/mark:/bin/sh
```

ls -l /mnt/files/

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 13 17:43 Games
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 13 04:57 Movies
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 12 06:28 MusicOrganized
drwxr-xr-x 13 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 13 15:32 _Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you guys for your help.

The system I am using doesn't have journalctl so I cannot post that. I also went to all of the samba log files in /var/log/samba/ but I could not find anything about the login attempts.

I tried connecting to it using AndSMB for Android, I tried connecting using Ubuntu Mate and I tried connecting to the share using Windows 10. All of them gave an Access Denied error with no more information.

However I found a solution to this problem:

- I created a group for every share;
- I added the users which are allowed to have access to those groups;
- I made the group the owner of the share;
- And finally I changed the permissions to 775 with chmod.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about the client you are using when trying to mount the shares.

One possibility is that the client you are mounting from uses an authentication method that has been made obsolete due to security issues. You can try

```
mount -o sec=ntlmssp //example.com/share /path/to/mount/dir
```

for fixing this issue.